# How do I count how many times I've divided in a recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm currently taking a course in Computer Science, I got an assignment to use either Python or pseudocode to ask the user to enter a digit, then divide it by 2, and then count how many divisions it takes to reach 1 (and add 1 more as it reaches 1). I've never coded before but I came up with this; but it only returns a 1 no matter what I input.

```
def divTime (t):
  if d <= 1:
    return t + 1
  else:
    return t + 1, divTime(d / 2)

d = input("Enter a number:")
t = 0
print (divTime)(t)
```

Comment: 1, Your number is actually a string, so `<= 1` may not be possible. 2, This is not how you call a function. This throws `NoneType` object is not callable.

Comment: 3, You passed (or tried to pass) a wrong parameter; what user entered is just wasted.

Answer (score 1):

You can add 1 to the recursive call with the input number floor-divided by 2, until the input number becomes 1, at which point return 1:

```
def divTime(d):
    if d == 1:
        return 1
    return 1 + divTime(d // 2)
```

so that:

```
print(divTime(1))
print(divTime(3))
print(divTime(9))
```

outputs:

```
1
2
4
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def div_time(d, t=0):
    if d < 1:
        return t
    else:
        return div_time(d/2, t+1)

d = input("Enter a number:")
print(f"t = {div_time(int(d))}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It always returns 1 because you're always passing it 0.

It looks like you're "thinking in loops" – you don't need a separate counter variable.

How many times does it take to divide:

- `k` smaller than 2? None.
- `k` greater than or equal to 2? One more than it takes to divide `k // 2`.

That is,

```
def divTime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 0
    return 1 + divTime(x // 2)
```

or

```
def divTime(x):
    return 0 if x < 2 else 1 + divTime(x //2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing a straight forward answer, I'll break the problem out into a few steps for students:

Ignore the input and edge cases for now, let's focus on writing a function that solves the problem at hand, then we may come back to providing an input to this function.

Problem statement confusion - You will often divide an odd number with a remainder, skipping the exact number 1 due to remainders. There is ambiguity with your problem from dealing with remainders - we will reword the problem statement:
Write a function that returns the number of times it takes to divide an input integer to become less than or equal to 1.

The next part is identifying the type of algorithm that can solve this type of problem. Since we want to run the function an unknown amount of times using the same function, this seems to be a perfect use case of recursion.

Say I provide 10 as an input. We then want to say 10/2=5 (count 1), 5/2=2.5 (count 2), 2.5/2=1.25 (count 3), 1.25/2=0.625 (count 4), return [4] counts.

Now we know we need a counter (x = x+1), recursion, and a return/print statement.

```
class solution:
    ''' this class will print the number of times it takes to divide an integer by 2 to become less than or equal to 1 '''
    def __init__(self):
        #this global counter will help us keep track of how many times we divide by two. we can use it in functions inside of this class.
        self.counter=0

    def counter_2(self, input_integer):
        #if the input number is less than or equal to 1 (our goal), then we finish by printing the counter.
        if input_integer<=1:
            print(self.counter, input_integer)
        #if the input is greater than 1, we need to keep dividing by 2.
        else:
            input_integer=input_integer/2
            #we divided by two, so make our counter increase by +1.
            self.counter=self.counter+1
            #use recursion to call our function again, using our current inputer_integer that we just divided by 2 and reassigned the value.
            self.counter_2(input_integer)

s=solution()
s.counter_2(10)
```